# Two different requests return the same results if the requests are made simultaneously

Tags: angular, httpclient

The problem is when I run two different `HttpClient` requests to my Spring Boot backend, I get the same result for both requests (the result I got is for the first request). This happens in ~30% of cases:

```
//request 1 with url_1= "http://localhost:9099/back/cars/list"
this.http.get(url_1, httpOptions).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
//request 2  with url_2= "http://localhost:9099/back/goods/list"
this.http.get(url_2, httpOptions).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

I think the reason why this is a front issue is because when I make a `system.out.println` in the backend, I see different responses for each requests.

I got always the correct results only if I make a sleep of 10 MILLISECONDS between the two requests.

Find bellow parts of the code that might help analyzing:

1- Parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { NotificationsComponent } from 'app/components/notifications/notifications.component'; 
import { HttpService } from 'app/pages/_services/http.service';
import { CarsListComponent } from '../cars-list/cars-list.component';
import { GoodsListComponent } from '../goods-list/goods-list.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chargement',
  templateUrl: './chargement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chargement.component.css']
})
export class ChargementComponent implements OnInit {
 
  @ViewChild(GoodsListComponent)
  private goodsListComponent!: GoodsListComponent;
  @ViewChild(CarsListComponent)
  private carsListComponent!: CarsListComponent;
  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private httpService:HttpService  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.curContainerId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');   
  }
 
    delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
    async getCustomerInfos(cust){ 
    localStorage.setItem("curCustomerACharger",JSON.stringify(cust)); 
    this.goodsListComponent.actualiser();
    //await this.delay(10);
    this.carsListComponent.actualiser();
  }
 
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="main-content" dir="ltr" i18n-dir>
 
    <div class="row">
        <mat-card class="col-md-3" style="padding: 0%;">
     
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0%;">
        
                <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false" style="background-color: white;">

                    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let cust of contCustomers" style="padding: 0%;"
                        (click)="getCustomerInfos(cust)" [value]="cust.id">
                        <div mat-line style="font-size: 12px;">
                             {{cust.name}} 
                        </div>
                      

                        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                    </mat-list-option>
                </mat-selection-list>
            </div>
        </mat-card>
        <div class="col-md-9" >
            
            <mat-tab-group>
                <mat-tab>
                    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                        <mat-icon><i class="nc-icon nc-app"></i></mat-icon>
                        Goods
                    </ng-template>
                    <app-goods-list>
                    </app-goods-list>
                </mat-tab>

                <mat-tab>
                    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                        <mat-icon>directions_car</mat-icon>
                        Cars
                    </ng-template>
                    <app-cars-list></app-cars-list>
                </mat-tab>

            </mat-tab-group>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2- The application Http service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private router: Router) { }

  post(url:string,data:any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, data, httpOptions);
  }
  put(url:string,data:any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(url+data.id, data, httpOptions);
  }
  delete(url:string ): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(url ,  httpOptions);
  }
  get(url:string ): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

3- The application HttpInterceptor :

```
import {HttpErrorResponse, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

import {TokenStorageService} from '../_services/token-storage.service';
import {throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {NotificationsComponent} from 'app/components/notifications/notifications.component';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {TechDialogElements} from '../common/dialog/TechDialogElements';
import { AuthService } from '../core/auth.service';
 
const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';    

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private token: TokenStorageService,
         private notifComponent: NotificationsComponent,
                public dialog: MatDialog,
                private auth:AuthService) {

    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

        let authReq = req;
        let curUrl = req.url;
        const token = this.token.getToken();
        console.log('in interceptor');
        if (curUrl.startsWith('/bck')) { 
            authReq = req.clone({
                url: 'http://localhost:9099' + req.url,
                headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, token)
            });
        }
        return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            });
        );
    }

}

export const authInterceptorProviders = [
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true}
];
```

Comment: could you, please provide the whole code of your component, and also check the network tab, to see if the data got from the server side is correct for both of the requests

Comment: Just added relevant parts of the code to the post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

All HttpClient methods return an RxJS Observable of something.
HTTP is a `request/response` protocol. You make a request, it returns a single response.
In general, an observable can return multiple values over time. An observable from HttpClient always emits a single value and then completes, never to emit again. [Angular Doc Http][1]

In this next example, we are going to use an operator called `forkJoin`. If you are familiar with `Promises`, this is very similar to `Promise.all()`.
Try, for making our requests parallel we're going to use `forkJoin`;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  loadedCharacter: {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let books = this.http.get("http://localhost:9099/back/books/list");
    let authors = this.http.get("http://localhost:9099/back/authors/list");

    forkJoin([books, authors]).subscribe(results => {
console.log("results ; ")
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: to make requests, i inject the HttpService  above and use it's get() function in my components, so i'm not writing them like you do. and when i used forkJoin like this:   the result is the same :  

```

  async getListData(curListConfig: ListDto) {
    this.queryOnProgress = true;
    forkJoin([
    this.httpService.post(this.url + '/list', curListConfig)]).subscribe(
      ([data]) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.items);
        this.length = data.size;
        this.queryOnProgress = false;
      }
    );
  } 
  
```